# LINQ to XML error: Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: xml, linq

This is the XML I am trying to parse:  http://pastebin.com/5mCqHQr3

This is the code used to parse the above XML document:

```cs
//  LINQ code to read the XML document
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + xml); // create the LINQ datasource
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(xml);

var query = from MWSdata in XElement.Parse("xml").Elements("AttributeSets") select MWSdata;
foreach (var data in query)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(data);
}
```

The full error is: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. (on the -var query statement).  How do I fix this?  I'm trying to get to each of the element's values (ns2:Author, ns2:Title, etc) and place them in textboxes.The program is written in C# .NET...

Comment: could you post the xml you want to parse, seem the link I don't your idea?

Comment: Here's part of it (the beginning)

<ns2:ItemAttributes xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
  <ns2:Author>Clarissa Pinkola Estes</ns2:Author>
  <ns2:Binding>Hardcover</ns2:Binding>
  <ns2:Feature>W</ns2:Feature>
  <ns2:ItemDimensions>
    <ns2:Height Units="inches">9.52</ns2:Height>
    <ns2:Length Units="inches">6.35</ns2:Length>
    <ns2:Width Units="inches">1.74</ns2:Width>
    <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">1.81</ns2:Weight>
  </ns2:ItemDimensions>

Comment: Could you pls edit your question instead of the comment

Comment: No, I can't paste it... it thinks it's just sentences and strips all of the XML formatting away... why can't you use the link?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error... this statement:

```cs
var query = from MWSdata in XElement.Parse("xml").Elements("AttributeSets") select MWSdata;
```

should be

```cs
var query = from MWSdata in XElement.Parse(xml).Elements("AttributeSets") select MWSdata;
```

The quotes around "xm" told the parser that was the data, when in reality it was an in-memory object.

Thanks Cuong for your time.